Force Chrome to use temp folder for downloads
Is there a way to force Chrome to store files in the temp folder and open them instead of downloading them to the default folder?
Essentially, if a user wants to just Open files, I don't want their downloads folder to fill up with those files.
I can get most of the way there by setting the Content-Disposition: inline header and choosing to `Always open files of this type' setting in chrome, but my problem is that the files are still stored in the 'Downloads' folder (or wherever the default is)
So, is there a way to have the following functionality
A) User clicks on file, is presented with 2 options

Open file - in this case, file is store in temp folder and opened by the default app
Download file - file is saved in the downloads folder

Is that possible if we have 2 different links ? For example I tried creating 2 different buttons - a 'Download' button with Content-Disposition: attachment and a 'Preview' button with Content-Disposition: inline but it doesn't really matter since the behaviour is mostly ignored by the browser based on the above settings.
I understand control we have in what happens with a file, so any suggestions or workarounds to get to the desired goal are welcome. I'm assuming something like this could be achieved with either an extension or a TamperMonkey script? Some JS in the front-end?
